# Hibernate Batch insert and update not working together in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have set the following hibernate prperties:

```
 hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
 hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
 hibernate.order_inserts=true
 hibernate.order_updates=true
```

When I am trying to only batch insert or only batch update then the batching is working fine but when I am doing both insert and update in the same batch then only the insert statements are getting batched while the update statements are executed individually. Any insight on this?

Comment: Can you post the code and hibernate query log? What version of mysql/driver/hibernate? To me, you seem to be doing right thing. Refer this https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/18/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/

Comment: It seems it was a driver problem. Previously I was using MySql connector 5.1.36 (also tried 5.1.44), but when I changed to 5.1.18, batching of both insert and update were happening.

Comment: Also, I am seeing the updates batched as multiple updates statement in a single line separated by semi-colon ? Is this correct?

Comment: If you see it like this then you're good -

Query:{[update Post set title=?, version=? where id=? and version=?][Blog Post no. 0,1,1,0]} {[update Post set title=?, version=? where id=? and version=?][Blog Post no. 1,1,2,0]} {[update Post set title=?, version=? where id=? and version=?][Blog Post no. 2,1,3,0]}

Comment: Yes, I am seeing something like that. Thanks